# Query which changes database in Spring Data Neo4j (4.1.2)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I created a @Query in a repository class (extends GraphRepository), which updates some nodes/relationships (it is simplier and faster to do this way instead of operating with Java objects). 
I cannot see the result, the session is not updated. 
Is there any solution to let the query update the session (eg. an annotation)?

Answer (score 1):

If the change creates/deletes relationships they should be visible when you query for affected objects again.

If the change updates properties they might not be visible as a cached instance may be returned.

Use `session.clear()` to clear the session and load affected objects again.